# Chinese Remainder Theorem: Show that $\phi$ is a Ring homomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

For an exercise, I need to show that

$$\phi: \mathbb{Z_n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_{n_1}} \times \mathbb{Z_{n_2}}; x \mapsto (x\mod n_1, x\mod n_2)$$
where $n = n_1 \cdot n_2$ and $n_1, n_2$ coprime is a Ring Homomorphism.

As far as I understand, this means I need to show that:
$\phi(a + b) = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$ and $\phi(a \cdot b) = \phi(a) \times \phi(b)$ and $\phi(1_{Z_n}) = (1_{Z_{n_1}},1_{Z_{n_2}})$.

My approach so far:
$\phi(a +b) = (a + b \mod n_1, a + b \mod n_2)$ 
and 
$\phi(a) + \phi(b) = (a \mod n_1, a \mod n_2) + (b \mod n_1, b \mod n_2)$.

Here I am stuck since it is not clear to me how $+$ and $\cdot$ are defined in $\mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}$. If they are defined as $(a \mod n_1, a \mod n_2) + (b \mod n_1, b \mod n_2) = (a + b \mod n_1, a +b \mod n_2)$, then wouldn't that make the exercise trivial?

Comment: Indeed, the operations on the direct product of rings is component-wise.

Comment: The additivity and multiplicativity of $\phi$ are indeed very easy to show. But do not forget to proof that $\phi$ is well-defined, i.e. for $x = y$ mod $n$ it must hold that $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$.

Comment: @DanielW.Thanks! Could you give me a hint on I could approach showing that $\phi$ is well defined?

Comment: If $x \equiv y$ mod $n$, then $x = kn + z = kn_1n_2 + z \equiv z$ mod $n_1$ and $y = ln + z = ln_1n_2 + z \equiv z$ mod $n_1$. The same is true mod $n_1$.